# Automatic Lineament Extraction from satellite images using ENVI?

Tags: dem, remote-sensing, envi

Can you tell me the steps of automatic lineament extraction from satellite images?

Can ENVI perform edge detection and the lineament extraction?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  There is a lot of potential in this question, however, you need to add more details to help make your question a good fit for this forum.  Please use the help center as a guide to asking good questions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Basically an edge is a rapid change of slope and therefore equivalent to large positive or negative values of the curvature of the DEM. 
As far as I've found in Google you can calculate curvature in ENVI: http://www.exelisvis.de/docs/ExtractingTopographicFeatures.html

Afterwards you should filter the result for large pos/neg values.

ENVI also offers to use IDL for edge detection. Follow maybe this link:
http://www.exelisvis.de/docs/DetectEdges.html